# How do I add two buttons side by side that are made up of an image?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out how exactly to add two buttons side by side. The button will be an image that the user clicks and it then goes to the URL. I tried adding a class in CSS with an inline display and added html calling that class on a button with an extra style tag added to it. It is not displaying the button though.

I am unsure how else to do it without adding the style tag directly in the html code if I needed the buttons side by side. That is the only way I know how to di it with display: inline;.

Here is how I am doing it:

CSS

```
.storebtns {

  display: inline;

}
```

HTML

```
<a class="storebtns" href="http://www.google.com" style="background-image: url(/img/btn.png);"></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work better, not sure if its feasible for you.

```
.storebtns
{
float:left;
width:100px;
}


<a class="storebtns" href="http://www.google.com">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSUZXG8Fd-auKjn_fLKsFtHMIarXLlcnDoTAvV86PSxmJFLwYgzJQ" width="100"/>
</a>
<a class="storebtns" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSHUhwMHx9nciceUQQ5X5Id7pK9pFeAXPRVc0BhunO5zt49OvNiag" width="100" />
</a>
```

here is a working example [Here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/randhirupesh/gLnWM/)

Comment: I ended up using this and it works great, the only issue is that the buttons aren't acting as links. I can't click them and the cursor doesn't change when hovering.

Answer (score 1):

I might not be understanding the question correctly, but if you want two buttons to be side by side and have an image background, try:

```
<a class="storebtns" href="#"></a>
```

and:

```
.storebtns {
    padding:100%;
    background:url("IMAGE_PATH_HERE");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work better, not sure if its feasible for you.

```
<a class="storebtns" href="http://www.google.com">
    <img src="/img/btn.png" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the buttons using `ul`, floating it and adding background images with css.

http://jsfiddle.net/nxEd5/

```
<body>
<h1>Click on a kitty.</p>
<div id="buttons">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Button1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Button2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!--end buttons-->
</body>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
ul li{
float:left;
list-style-type:none;

}

ul li a{
padding:40px;
text-decoration:none;
text-indent:-9999px;
background:url(img.jpg) no-repeat;
opacity:0.5;
display:inline-block;
}

ul li a:hover{
opacity:1.0;
}
```